# For Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2, where can I adjust access/concurrency settings?

Tags: azure, configuration, settings, azure-data-lake-gen2

We have an Azure functions application that uses a Data Lake Storage Gen2 account.  We have these default settings

[image]

For a given connection, where or how do I configure the setting that governs concurrent connections to our account?  Or are there other settings that we can adjust that govern concurrency or throughput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure Data Lake Gen2, there are these [authorization mechanisms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control-model) to adjust access:

- Shared Key authorization
- Shared access signature (SAS) authorization
- Role-based access control (Azure RBAC)
- Access control lists (ACL)

And there is no setting of concurrent connections in Azure Data Lake Gen2.